# Should i use gunicorn with a python flaks application if i will put in a docker and then use it in a cloud environment

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, gunicorn

should i use gunicorn with a python flaks application if i will put in a docker and then use it in a cloud environment.

i have seen a lot of tutorials on how to do a flask application and deploy to a cloud service as a docker Image,

1. make the flask application
2. make the last line in docker with:

   ```
    CMD ["python", "my_app.py"]
   ```
3. push the image and let the cloud service like AWS or azure use their load balancer with the amount of cpu and memeory you want to set as rule before spining another instance.

but i got into this tutorial and is using gunicorn
https://levelup.gitconnected.com/usage-of-gunicorn-for-deploying-python-web-applications-1e296618e1ab
where all the steps are the same, just the last line of the docker would be

```
CMD ["python" "-m", "gunicorn", "my_app:app"]
```

now uses the gnunicorn wsgi

and same way push that image to be use in the web application of the cloud.

i understand gunicorn can add more workers and thread as arguments in the cli; what would be the better approach or is one better than other?

Thanks guys.

Comment: Flask itself is pretty clear about using the development server in production.

Comment: Yes, this approach is the best.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should always use a production server. As covered the the Flask docs, Deploy to Production: [Run with a Production Server](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/tutorial/deploy/#run-with-a-production-server):

> you should not use the built-in development server (flask run). The development server is provided by Werkzeug for convenience, but is not designed to be particularly efficient, stable, or secure.

Using gunicorn (or any other production WSGI server) is a necessary practice for deploying to production for speed, stability, and security. These concerns still persist, **even if your app is deployed behind a load-balancer or proxy** (like AWS load balancer). Both are necessary (you don't want to expose your WSGI server directly to the open internet, either, it should be behind a proper load balancer / proxy).